# How to enable installation packages, sudo apt-get update in TTY in 18.04

Tags: apt, updates, dpkg

I tried to remove python3.6 by using this command `sudo --purge configure python3.6` then after processing this code it seems all configurations were deleted. then after rebooting system my PC can not back to the desktop it returns to tty1 and can not install any dependencies and cannot update the system. When I try `sudo apt-get update`

[image: this is about update system screenshot is here]

[image: this is about update system screenshot is here]

When I tried to install `sudo apt-get install VLC` I got this.

[image: install any application screenshot is here]

I can not back to ubuntu-desktop and even booting not work when I was booting and reached to Install Ubuntu it turns to a black screen.

Comment: Reinstalling will be the short pain.

Answer (score 0):

I would venture to say that you are in need of a complete reinstall. Deleting all configuration files will be extremely hard to fix. Also NEVER delete Python. If you need other versions, learn to use virtual Python environments.

Comment: So how can I reinstall I only get tty(1-6) no else

Comment: I meant that you will need to create a Ubuntu installation USB (or disk) and completely reinstall the OS.

Comment: I did but when I reach on install ubuntu it becomes a black screen and nothing else.